# cordova checkConnection() onload is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, cordova

I builded a function to check the internet-connection from the device

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function checkConnection() {
     var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

     var states = {};
     states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'unknown';
     states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'ethernet';
     states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'wifi';
     states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = '2g';
     states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = '3g';
     states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = '4g';
     states[Connection.CELL]     = 'cell';
     states[Connection.NONE]     = 'none';


    if (states[networkState] == 'unknown' || states[networkState] == '2g' || states[networkState] == 'cell' || states[networkState] == 'none') 
    {
      alert('error');
    }

    else
    {
      alert('good');
    }
}
window.onload = checkConnection;
</script>
```

On inital load, i get the error alert, although i hava WIFI oder 3/4G connection activated. If the page is rendered and i'm clicking on a button to open the function again, i get the correct message.

My function `checkConnection` is near end of `body`, my `cordova.js` in the `header`.

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call **checkConnection** function after **deviceready** event fired, if u call before **deviceready** the libraries may or may not loaded properly so you will get the error.

```
document.addEventListenr("deviceready",checkConnection,
false);
```

This should work as expected.

Comment: checkConnection(); is the last function which is loaded. But it doesn't work. I put it into after `$(document).ready(function() { checkConnection(); ...` and also in `deviceready`

Comment: `document.addEventListener("deviceready", checkConnection, false);` works for me